# The degree of 'pushiness' perceived in the phrase « inviter qn à faire qch »

Tags: sens

> Je t'**invite** à nous suivre dans notre établissement.

I use « inviter qn à faire qch » all the time, but I'm not fully clear how strongly you are suggesting that someone do something by using this phrase.

> 1. Please do so only if you like. {without wishing to push you into doing that}
> 2. Please do so. {in a neutral tone}
> 3. I urge you to do so. {might come across as pushy}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je dirais que ça dépend de ce qui suit, de ce qu'on est invité à faire.

- Le surveillant de salle à la fin d'un examen :

  > Je vous invite à me remettre vos copies.
- Le directeur d'une usine à un de ses employés :

  > Je vous invite à me suivre dans mon bureau.

  → ce sont des ordres sans appel. On sait qu'il y aura une sanction en cas de refus.
- Le directeur d'une usine à des personnalités qui viennent visiter les installations :
- > Je vous invite à me  suivre dans notre établissement.

  → c'est une façon polie de leur dire d'entrer à l'intérieur.
- > Cette idée est idiote, je t'invite à la rejeter.

  → c'est une suggestion assez appuyée.
- En fin de réunion de travail :

  > Je vous invite à me communiquer vos propositions.

  →  c'est une simple suggestion.
- > Terminus du train. Tous les voyageurs sont invités à descendre de voiture.

  → c'est un conseil.

Comment: Pour le train ça me semble fortement obligatoire.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Il n'y a pas d'amende si on ne descends pas à l'écoute de l'annone au terminus, encore moins de risque de se faire renvoyer par son patron. Le seul risque c'est de se retrouver ailleurs si le train repars sans avoir été vérifié (fréquent) ou se voir dire de sortir par un agent SNCF, et là il ne prie plus de sortir, il utilise l'impératif ou un verbe indiquant une obligation donc pour moi l'annonce correspond bien à un conseil.

Answer (score 0):

It is polite, not pushy, level 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is a polite form of suggestion and implies you should do it, but without being pushy: more like an advice.

> Je t'invite à me suivre dans notre établissement

=> you don't have to if you don't want to, but you would benefit from doing it

---

As Laure says, you won't interpret it the same depending on who says it to you, but I think that's a general rule and isn't specific to the expression "Je t'invite à..."